# Client gets wrong DHCP lease time

Tags: network, time-machine, airport

I am running OpenWRT 23.05.2 r23630 on a Linksys WRT1200AC router for my home network. The DHCP server on this router is set to give all clients a lease time of 7 days. This works fine for all the clients (a total of 25) with the exception of the Apple Time Capsule which I use for my Mac Time Machine backup. This Time Capsule is in bridge mode, has wireless disabled and is wired to the network. The Time Capsule receives all its network settings correctly from the DHCP server except for the lease time which ends up being 24 hours. I have tried giving it a static IP address and explicitly setting the lease time in the static lease definition to values different than 24 hours and in this way I can get the Time Machine to accept values that are less than 24 hours, but for anything greater it goes to 24 hours.

I will greatly appreciate any help in understanding why it seems not possible to give the Time Capsule a lease time greater than 24 hours.

Comment: I know that this does not answer your question but I always reserved a block of IPs outside the DHCP range to assign to server/router type devices. So my NAS, switch, secondary WiFi, etc. always had a known address and the rest just were just Macs and PCs that came and went on the network. Not sure if that would work for you or not, but it did for me.

Comment: Why does it matter if it renews its lease every day?

Comment: I do something similar to what Steve is pointing out (thanks Steve!) but in my case I use the DHCP server to assign a static IP to such clients with a never-expiring lease; in that way I can manage all clients from one place. Not saying that approach is better, it's just an old habit. However, the Time Capsule stubbornly goes to its own 24-hour preference. To Gilby: it doesn't really matter in any practical way, but I'm just curious to find out what causes this behavior. All my own investigations have found nothing.

Comment: I don't "know", but guessing that the Time Capsule has a builtin max time before renewing the lease. I can't find a reference for this.